# How to run a code within a loop but only show every 3 times it runs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop running for wordpress that calls category images

```
<ul>
 <?php foreach (get_terms('your_taxonomy') as $cat) : ?>
 <li>
 <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
 <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'your_taxonomy'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>
 </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Now the trick is (don't know if its possible) I want that after every 3 images a div to show for adwords. I but I don't want every other one as I believe it will do if I added it part of the wordpress loop... Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Put a counter inside the loop and use modulo.

Comment: In order to accomplish this you will have to use an incrementing variable along with the modulus operator: `if($i+=1 % 3 == 0){//echo adword}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a counter, like this:

```
<ul>
<?php
   $i=0; 
   foreach (get_terms('your_taxonomy') as $cat) : 
?>
 <li>
 <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
 <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'your_taxonomy'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>
 </li>
 <?php 
   $i++;
   if(!$i%3) {
      echo '<div>Here is your div</div>';
   }
   endforeach; 
 ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Brandon Turpy, if you are satisfied with this answer, don't forget to accept it as correct.